# Facing neutron networking issues in openstack( deployed through conjure-up openstack with kvm )

Tags: networking, juju, openstack, openstack-autopilot, conjure-up

I am facing network issues in Openstack. My openstack(MaaS + JuJu + Conjure-up) setup got deployed successfully but when i spin up an instance, there is no internet connectivity and my router is also not getting pinged from outside network(*My Openstack VM can ping the router*).

Any leads would be really helpful.

**Traceroute o/p:**

```
$sudo ip netns exec qrouter-ce0ba09f-8220-4414-91e2-b6896b596aef traceroute 8.8.8.8  
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  
1  172.18.0.111 (172.18.0.111)  2999.458 ms !H  2999.416 ms !H  2999.409 ms !H
```

**iptables o/p from Router:**

[image]

**iptables NAT rules from Router**

```
$ sudo ip netns exec qrouter-ce0ba09f-8220-4414-91e2-b6896b596aef iptables -t nat -L

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
neutron-l3-agent-POSTROUTING  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
neutron-postrouting-bottom  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             172.18.0.108         to:10.0.0.4

Chain neutron-l3-agent-POSTROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! ctstate DNAT

Chain neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.169.254      tcp dpt:http redir ports 9697
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             172.18.0.108         to:10.0.0.4

Chain neutron-l3-agent-float-snat (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  10.0.0.4             anywhere             to:172.18.0.108

Chain neutron-l3-agent-snat (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
neutron-l3-agent-float-snat  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
SNAT       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             to:172.18.0.111
SNAT       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match ! 0x2/0xffff ctstate DNAT to:172.18.0.111

Chain neutron-postrouting-bottom (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
neutron-l3-agent-snat  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Perform source NAT on outgoing traffic. */
```

Comment: Can you ping any public ip from tenant router?

Comment: nope .. i tried pinging 8.8.8.8 and its dint connect .

Comment: Do you have appropriate configured external network, route and nat enabled? Add this info in your question.

Comment: All configurations are properly , my router is SNAT enabled.  External network is also resolvable , i am using the same network as the MaaS. I created a reserve range in MaaS and using this range as External network in Openstack.

Comment: Is it necessary to have 2 NIC cards ..?? bcos my servers are having 1 NIC card with 2 ports. Will this work ..??

Comment: @2707974  Is it necessary to have 2 NIC cards ..?? bcos my servers are having 1 NIC card with 2 ports. Will this work ..??

Comment: Sorry, I was offline. Not it is not necessery to have two nic. Ok, to move further with problem solving. Go to tenant router and do `traceroute` to any public address. This will show you on with tenant router interface traffic go out. If `traceroute` do not go from router, check `ip route`. Please give me output of `traceroute`, `iptables` rules and router from tenant router.

Comment: @2707974 i attached the output details in the question from the openstack router. After doing the traceroute, the traffic is not crossing the router.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text. Instead, paste the text, select it in the editor, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Hi, your router say `!H`. `!H` means that your machine received ICMP message `destination host unreachable` from the host indicated in the traceroute output. Can you please give output from `iptables -t nat -L` maybe nat rules is not good.

Comment: @2707974 I updated the output of NAT rules , i am not so familiar with neutron but i am not able to access the 169.254.169.254 (metdata server virtual IP).

Comment: Based on your output from `iptables` VM is on `10.0.0.4` and floating ip for VM is `172.18.0.108`. Router wan interface is `172.18.0.111`. I guess that is problem on next hop form tenant router. Also if you must do `NAT` one more time, if you want on internet,  because  `172.18.x.x` are private ip addresses. What is a next hop?

Comment: @2707974 i have a next hop to a gateway on the same subnet from 172.18.x.x.   Basically, my MaaS is also hosted on the same subnet. I created a reserve range in maas subnet setting and i'm using this range as my floating IP pool in openstack for testing purpose.

Comment: I guess that next hop, after `MAAS` is your router. Router do `NAT` for net `172.18.x.x`? Do your router receive packet/traffic from `MAAS`?

Comment: @2707974  My router do not receive any packet from MAAS.  My MAAS servers and cotainers(where openstack components are hosted) are able to communicate with the Gateway. But my openstack router is not able to communicate with the gateway or any machine which are hosted in the same subnet(as MAAS & Openstack componets). And just curious,could this be any bridging issue between Juju environment(openstack services) and openstack router(hosted on neutron-gateway) ..??